Playwright: waitForURL fails with timeout in Mozilla - Azure CI/CD
I have this e2e test :

import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test"

test.describe("ChooseApp Page", () => {
  test("should display correct content and navigate to app pages", async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("./6XDCIRI/choose-app")

    // Check if the main title is present
    await expect(page.locator("text=Wählen Sie Ihre App")).toBeVisible()

    // Check if Solar Analytics Card is present
    const solarAnalyticsCard = page.getByTestId("choose-app-0")
    await expect(solarAnalyticsCard).toBeVisible()

    // Test navigation for Solar Analytics
    await solarAnalyticsCard.click()
    await page.waitForURL("./6XDCIRI/solar-analytics/electricity-requirements")
  })
})


Locally, it's passed for Chromium and Mozilla, but in Azure CI/CD it fails ( timeout ) only for Mozilla:
Local

Azure CI/CD

Playwright config
/* eslint-disable lines-around-comment */

/* eslint-disable capitalized-comments */
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import path from "path"

/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
const envFile = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? ".env.production" : ".env.testing"

dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, envFile) })
/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
// Use process.env.PORT by default and fallback to port 3000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

// Set webServer.url and use.baseURL with the location of the WebServer respecting the correct set port
const baseURL = `http://localhost:${PORT}`

export default defineConfig({
  timeout: 180000,

  testDir: path.join(__dirname, "e2e"),

  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,

  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,

  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,

  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,

  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: "html",

  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL,

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: "on-first-retry",
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    { name: "setup", testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/ },
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],

        storageState: "playwright/.auth/user.json",
      },
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },

    {
      name: "firefox",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Firefox"], storageState: "playwright/.auth/user.json" },
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },

    // {
    //   name: "webkit",
    //   use: { ...devices["Desktop Safari"] },
    // },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge' },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Google Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' },
    // },
  ],

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  webServer: {
    command: "npm run dev",
    url: baseURL,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
})




What does the trace report show for Firefox?

It's hard to say without looking at the trace, but it might be that it's because you're using .waitForURL() with a relative path. I'd recommend using expect for your navigation assertion instead of .waitForURL(), something like:
test.describe('ChooseApp Page', () => {
  test('should display correct content and navigate to app pages',
      async ({page}) => {
        await page.goto('./6XDCIRI/choose-app');

        // Check if the main title is present
        await expect(page.locator('text=Wählen Sie Ihre App'))
            .toBeVisible();

        // Check if Solar Analytics Card is present
        const solarAnalyticsCard = page.getByTestId('choose-app-0');
        await expect(solarAnalyticsCard)
            .toBeVisible();

        // Test navigation for Solar Analytics
        await solarAnalyticsCard.click();
        const relativePath = /\/6XDCIRI\/solar-analytics\/electricity-requirements/;
        await expect(async () => {
          expect(page.url())
              .toMatch(relativePath);
        })
            .toPass({timeout: 10000, intervals: [100]});
      });
});

await expect(async()=>{}).toPass() is a very nice way to repeatedly test some block of code. Just make sure if your assertions in the callback are asynchronous, that they have a shorter timeout than your expect().toPass() timeout, or it won't actually retry.
